# My html file is not responding to ajax request in express.js application

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax, express

In my express application my root file app.js rendering a.html in 'a' folder but a.html is not responding to any ajax code written in ajax.js. I've shown these files below-

**app.js**

```js
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.set(express.static('./a'));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/a/a.html');
});
app.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
```

**a.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="button"></button>
  <script src="ajax.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**ajax.js**

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', trigger);

function trigger() {
  var xhr = XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open('GET', 'blah.txt', true);

  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status == 200) {
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
}
```

*Here I'm providing some screenshots of directory and result*

[image: Directory]
**Directory**

[image: End Result]
**End Result**

Answer (score 0):

The file that you are trying to load by ajax is `blah.txt`, whereas the file in `a` directory is `blah` without extension, try to rename it to `blah.txt` or remove `.txt` extension from the ajax url:

```
xhr.open('GET', '/blah', true);
```

Comment: Try to declare static folder like this: `app.set(express.static('a'));`